# Use <a name=""> in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, load, href

i try to use  in legend. And when i click a button that will run the function, I want to load same page but the desired position.

In view i use:

```
<a name="#C1"> <legend>Adicionar produto/serviço: </legend> </a>
```

But which is what I call the "#C1"? In controller?

Thanks for help

Comment: could you try to explain again what you're trying to do? it's not clear...

Comment: well, when i click in a button (execute a function in controller), recharge the page in place of "#C1". Image that C1 is in the middle of the page, reload the page again want to carry the middle of the page (site C1)

Comment: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/119231/#590063

Comment: I couldn't understand a word... (ok, I understand each individual word, but the way they follow each other doesn't make any sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand from your question is that you want to run a controller method but you also want to specify the desired position of the page than try this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/controller/method/#contact"><label>Adicionar produto/serviço:</label></a>
```

Where `controller` is the name of your controller and `method` is the name of your `function` and `base_url()` is what you defined in the `application/config/config.php`

Than in the view file give the desired section `id` as `id="contact"`

Assume you have the contact div in the footer give its `id` as `contact`

```
<div id="contact"></div>
```

And the page will scroll down to the contact section of the page once the link will be clicked